# "before script" mechanism in pytest

Tags: python, plugins, hook, pytest, fixtures

So I have app that uses couchdb and I'm writing pytests.

The problem is that importing anything causing `ConnectionRefusedError`.

Mocking `couchdb.Server` fix this but I can't figure out how to do it globally.

Session scooped fixture doesn't cut it because they are executed before the first test while the error is raised on item collection.

So obviously I need to execute a piece of code before item collection. I've been reading about hooks and look into plugins but I can't get this to work.

What do i actually need to do for pytest to run something before item collection?

Comment: create a `conftest.py` file in the project root dir, add [custom init hook impl](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#initialization-hooks) there, e.g. `def pytest_configure(config): print('hello world')`

Comment: I already have conftest file full of fixtures and there are also imports causing this error.

Comment: Tried creating multiple conftest files. Doesn't work, looks like it imports everything before calling any functions.

Comment: Will this be different if the conftest is part of registered plugin?

Comment: _I already have conftest and there are also imports_ - then why not mocking stuff in `conftest` before the imports? If this isn't working, create a [mcve] and add it to the question.